# How to solve this: "cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const GLdouble' to 'const GLdouble *"?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

In a calling to an OpenGL function, I had the following error:

> error C2664: cannot convert parameter 1 from `'const GLdouble'` to `'const GLdouble *'`

Is it strange a bit !!

```
const GLdouble someColor = 30.0;
```

The calling:

```
glColor3dv(someColor);
```

Any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`glColor3dv` takes a pointer to the initial element of an array of three `GLdouble`s (one each for the red, green, and blue channels).  You are passing it a single `GLdouble` by value.

Either you need an array of `GLdouble`s or you need to use one of the other `glColor` functions (like `glColor3d`).